# Looking for a C alternative to C#'s System.Text.ASCIIEncoding()

Tags: c#, c

I'm not friendly with C# programming, so
I don't know what can be replaced for below C# function(method?) in C language:

```
public string ToAscii(byte[] data)
{
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding decoder = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    return decoder.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Does anyone have a good idea or clue how to replace the above method in C language?

Comment: If you want any help from those who know C but don't know Java then you should say a little bit about what this function is actually doing.

Comment: That changes the byte array into a Java string. In C, all you need to do is copy the bytes into your string. No conversion is necessary. But what kind of input do you get the bytes from? It's rare not to get them as a char buffer already.

Comment: ah! thank you for giving me a great advice... I should have done alike what you told me!!! thank you!!

Comment: @taskinoor Java strings consists of 16 bit chars, so if you have an array of bytes, you'll need to convert each of those bytes into a char. That's basically what the function does. But in C, it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: these are about html5 websocket stuff!!! I write the site having above code just for in case you wanna see
http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2012/01/18/websockets-with-rfc-6455/

Comment: This seems to be C# code, *not* Java (:

Comment: If that's java I'll eat my hat..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strcpy`:

```
char *newString = malloc(strlen(input) + 1);
strcpy(newString, input);

// don't forget to free 'newString'!
```

Comment: How is that supposed to translate between ASCII and UTF-16?

Comment: @CodeInChaos a C-string IS ASCII already, for UTF-16, you need a different type, like `unichar`.

Comment: The given C# code translates ASCII to UTF-16. But the OPs question is so bad that it's not clear what he actually wants.